# How to monitor call activity of all users in domain and join calls using UCMA Trusted Application

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucma

So my goal is to create an UCMA Trusted Application that is able to monitor all of the calls happening in the Skype for Business on premises domain and automatically record those calls for certain users. But i'm struggling to wrap my head around the way to implement that, as i've found info on UCMA not being able to give you such rights. And the solution i've stumbleb uppon is to intercept all incoming calls using fake endpints and then rout them the way i need.
If that's true, i would really appreciate suggestions on other ways to put together such a piece of software.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want with just a UCMA application.

There are three ways to do what you want:

- Enable and use the [CDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/manage/health-and-monitoring/call-detail-recording-cdr) (call detail recording) database in SfB
- Use the [SDN SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/skype-for-business-sdn-interface) to "monitor" the call media traffic and track calls that way
- Use the [Server SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/lync/server-sdk/lync-server-2013-sdk-documentation) to create a SIP proxy and track calls by tracking the SIP traffic

I would recommend that you use the CDR as it's the easiest to understand and use.  The problem that it's not real time, the records will "show up" sometime after the fact.  If that's ok then that's the best way.

The other ways get way more complex as it requires that you understand how SIP works.  The best way for tracking all calls live is the server SIP proxy but it can be very complex (as it can impact the performance of the Skype FE) and requires a good knowledge of how SIP works.